# How to deselect a radio button in onclick of one radio button in Lotus Notes Client Application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to deselect the radio button in on-click of another radio button in Notes client Application. How to achieve it?

Appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the value of the radio button you want to deselect to `""`

*Example:*

Radio button A shall be automatically deselected when radio button B gets selected and vice versa:

- set option "Refresh fields on keyword change" in radio button A and B
- enter Input Translation formula for radio button A
  `@If(SelectedRadioButton = "A" & B != ""; ""; @ThisValue)`
- enter Input Translation formula for radio button B
  `@If(SelectedRadioButton = "B" & A != ""; ""; @ThisValue)`
- add a hidden computed for display text field "SelectedRadioButton" behind both radio buttons with the formula
  `@If(A != ""; "A"; B != ""; "B"; "")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Knut.. I don't know which event helps me to execute that in Notes Client

Comment: @Sathish: I added an example to show how to set value to "".

Comment: No, it doesn't. This would be a bit more complicated. Do you really need *two* separated radio button fields? The normal way is to use *one* radio button field and to define a choices list.

Comment: Yeah i need two separated radio buttons, otherwise two column headers collapsing

Comment: I updated my answer. It works in both directions now.

Comment: should i add "SelectedRadioButton" field behind two radio buttons? in that case, do we need to change formula or how it works?

Comment: As of now when i click radio button, it is not selecting also. Hope i only didn't get your answers properly. Appreciate if you help me more regarding this Knut

Comment: Yes, this field has to be behind the radio button fields and no, we don't need to change formula.